# tengo un problema con el while, no he logrado encontrar el error, si alguien me puede echar una mano

Tags: javascript, java, html, while, switch

ya llevo bastante tiempo intentando encontrar el error y creo que es en el while ya que lo demas creo que lo tengo bien no tengo a quien recurrir por eso voy con vosotros, no soy el mejor en la programación lo admito y mi ultimo recurso es aquí , alguien que me ayude, el código va de un script que permita leer un numero de mes de teclado y apartir de ese mes calcular la productividad. la productividad es 100 + el factor del mes. Muchas gracias.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mes, resulatdo, factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4, factor5;

    mes = parseInt(prompt("Favor ingresar opcion: "));

while (mes!= 13){

 resultado=100
 factor1=15
 factor2=17
 factor3=20
 factor4=21
 factor5=0
 
    switch (mes) {
    case 1: console.log( resultado + factor1);
    break;
    
    case 2: console.log(resultado + factor1);
    break;
    
    case 3: console.log(resultado + factor1);
    break;
    
    case 4: console.log(resulatdo + factor2);
    break;
    
    case 5: console.log( resultado + factor2);
    break;
    
    case 6: console.log(resulatdo + factor2);
    break;
    
    case 7: console.log(factor5);
    break;
    
    case 8: console.log(factor5);
    break;

    case 9: console.log( resultado + factor3);
    break;
    
    case 10: console.log(resultado + factor3);
    break;
    
    case 11: console.log(resultado + factor3);
    break;
    
    case 12: console.log(resultado + factor4);
    break;
    
    case 13: break;

    default: console.log("mes");
    break;
    }
}
    </script>
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Mirate esta pregunta, viene a ser bastante identica a la tuya, y hace tambien pocas horas, fijo que haceis el mismo curso: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/535762/no-me-funciona-el-while-nose-que-hacer-estoy-desesperado

Comment: Javascript es un lenguaje, Java es otro. Lo que usas aquí es JavaScript, no Java. Un coche y un yate son medios de transporte los dos, pero no me atrevería a ir por la autopista en el yate, ni a cruzar el océano en un coche.

Comment: Solo un comentario, en la declaracion de variables dice 'resulatdo' y dentro del while 'resultado'.
Por otro lado, creo que es conveniente que muestres cual es el error que te salta así es mas fácil para la comunidad ayudarte a resolverlo. Saludos,

Comment: No des vueltas: pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo, y en el cuerpo el resultado esperado y el obtenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Aquí no hacemos depuración de código. Y como te han indicado: **JavaScript != Java**. Elimina la etiqueta no relacionada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While se utiliza para un bucle. Lo que entiendo que quieres hacer es que si el més introducido por el prompt es un mes de año aplicar el switch. Para esto lo mejor es utilizar un condicional if.

En tu caso yo utilizarira un condicional if si el mes introducido es menor o igual a 13:

```js
const resultado=100
const factor1=15
const factor2=17
const factor3=20
const factor4=21
const factor5=0

const mes = parseInt(prompt('Introduce un mes:'))

if (mes <= 13) {
  
    switch (mes) {
        case 1: 
        console.log( resultado + factor1);
            break;
    case 2: 
        console.log(resultado + factor1);
            break;
    case 3: 
        console.log(resultado + factor1);
            break;
    case 4: 
        console.log(resultado + factor2);
            break;
    case 5: 
        console.log( resultado + factor2);
        break;
    case 6: 
        console.log(resultado + factor2);
        break;
    case 7:  
        console.log(factor5);
        break;
    case 8: 
        console.log(factor5);
        break;
    case 9: 
        console.log( resultado + factor3);
        break;
    case 10: 
        console.log(resultado + factor3);
        break;
    case 11:
        console.log(resultado + factor3);
        break;
    case 12: 
        console.log(resultado + factor4);
        break;
    default: 
        console.log("mes");
    }
} else {
  console.log('El numero no es valido')
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias :)